# Find a file containing a class (based on __autoload), but don't include it

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am using Composer to load PHP dependencies. Given the name of the class I want to find path of the file where this class is defined, but don't include it.

Example:

```
echo get_file_for_class('Carbon\\Carbon');
```

Output:

```
vendor/briannesbitt/Carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Reflection Class. http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Carbon\\Carbon');
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

There are some additional useful class methods you could also play around with, to determine its parent, if it inherits from one, or its start line.

```
$reflector->getParentClass();
```